# Symfony How to get Kernel/ Kernel interface

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to get the KernelInterface object for the parameter of the getMime method but I have no idee where to look and how to find it. I need this method to run a command.

```
<?php


namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;


class MimeController extends AbstractController
{
    public function getMime($video, KernelInterface $kernel)
    {
        $application = new Application($kernel);
        $application->setAutoExit(false);

        $input = new ArrayInput([
            'command' => 'get-video-mime',
            'fooArgument' => $video,

        ]);
        $output = new BufferedOutput();
        try {
            $application->run($input, $output);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
        }

        $content = $output->fetch();

        // return new Response(""), if you used NullOutput()
        return $content;
    }
}
```

Comment: this looks a lot like https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/command_in_controller.html ... do you have any error message? also, do you think you have the right approach?

Comment: I can't even run it because I have no idea what KernelInterface is about

Comment: I honestly don't know on which level of familiarity with PHP or Symfony you're at. Which is saying, I can't gauge what kind of answer you're looking for.

Comment: What do yu want to achieve? Why do you want to start a new application within a controller? Why not seperate everything properly to different services such that you can call the same logic from your command and from your controller?

Comment: As several of the commentators have indicated, your approach is flawed.  However, in an attempt to allow you a better chance of understanding why it is flawed I would just like to point out that taking a peek at public/index.php reveals that $kernel is actually a global variable.  So you can access it in your controller action.  You shouldn't but again, by doing so perhaps you will have a better chance of understanding why it is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness the `kernel` service is public and can be get from the container (you have to add the `'kernel' => KernelInterface::class` to the subscribed services of `AbstractController`)

However, this is not a good way to resolve your problem:

- first of all, do not ever instantiate a new `Application` object inside your controller. It is designed to be used by a console script and could call `exit` or `die`, terminating your controller and printing out something to the end user.
- if you have some custom logic to calculate mime types, create a service and call that service from the controller and the console command. This way you can de-dupe your code and isolate responsabilities.
- check if there's something that's resolve the problem for you: symfony has a `Mime` component that exposes a service you can use in your controller to calculate a mime type of a file.
- if you need to invoke a shell command (if you have no other option), use the symfony `Process` component. It is specifically desinged to execute a shell script and give you access to the result. Do not do this as a shortcut, it is a bad practice and could lead to very bad problems (hard to debug).